# How to promise completion of multiple threads?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, executorservice

I'm kinda new to the MultiThreading concept in java.
This question's title may have a similarity to previous questions on this topic but still, despite looking in the answers, I have yet succeeded accomplishing the following:

say on MainActivity I have a nested for loop. and in the inner loop I am running a method from another class that takes an interface as a callback, something like this:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_display_prices, container, false);

    return v;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++){
              CategoryItemsDataSource.getCategoryItemsData(url, new CategoryItemsDataSource.OnCategoryItemsDataArrived() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCategoryItemsDataArrived(List<ProductItem> data, Exception e) {
                             getActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                   //display retrieved data on UIThread...
                             });

                        }
              });
        }
    }

}
```

**CategoryItemDataSource.java**

```
 public class CategoryItemsDataSource {

public interface OnCategoryItemsDataArrived {
    void onCategoryItemsDataArrived(List<ProductItem> data, Exception e);
}

public static void getCategoryItemsData(final String[] url, final OnCategoryItemsDataArrived listener){

    ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    service.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                List<ProductItem> data = new ArrayList<>();
                //retreiving data from web and appending to List<> Data....
                }
                listener.onCategoryItemsDataArrived(data, null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                listener.onCategoryItemsDataArrived(null, e);
            }
        }
    });
    service.shutdown();
}
```

I don't know how to access the ExecutorService instance from the CategoryItemDataSource class [I.E if I need to at all], in the MainActivity. hence, how  am I suppose to ensure/promise completion of all the several threads generated in the inner loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a counter variable; in the loop, increment the counter each time a new task is submitted to the executor. In the `onCategoryItemsDataArrived` method, decrement that counter; when it become zero, all tasks are finished. Provide atomic access to the counter: use `AtomicInteger`, or `synchronized` statement.

Comment: It worked for me. thanks. but why if it gets to zero all tasks are finished for sure? can't there be a possibility for instance: first task gets submitted and gets finished before second task is submitted??

Comment: @HudiIlfeld yes you are right. Instead of incrementing, counter must be set to the maximal number at the initialization.

Comment: yeah,  that's what I thought. yet even by setting the initial as 0 - the program still works successfully which got me to realize that [in my case at least], submission of tasks will always be faster then the finalization, therefore it can never reach the 0 before all tasks completed, otherwise I can't figure how my program runs successfully like your first solution

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know how to access the ExecutorService instance from the CategoryItemDataSource class [I.E if I need to at all], in the MainActivity. hence, how am I suppose to ensure/promise completion of all the several threads generated in the inner loop?

There are a couple ways to do this but the best way would be for the `getCategoryItemsData(...)` method to return `Future` object returned by the `service.submit(...)` command (as opposed to `service.execute(...)`).  Then you can save those `Future`s in an array and call `future.get(...)` on them to wait for them to finish.  Doing this is similar to calling `thread.join()` if you are managing the threads yourself.

Something like:

```
int numJobs = 4;
// this might need to be Future<Void> or something
Future<?>[] futures = new Future<>[numJobs];
for (i = 0; i < numJobs; i++) {
    futures[i] = CategoryItemsDataSource.getCategoryItemsData(...);
}
for (Future<?> future : futures) {
    // waits for each of the jobs to finish, you'll need to handle the exceptions
    future.get();
}
```

But one thing that is strange is that you are creating a new `ExecutorService` each time.  I doubt that you want to do that.  I'd create one service as a field in `CategoryItemsDataSource` and then have each of the `getCategoryItemsData(...)` calls submit their jobs to the same service.

Comment: regarding your suggestion to create one. global service field in CategoryItemsDataSource, doing so I get the following error:  _java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task hudiilfeld.theshoppingequalizer.sources.CategoryItemsDataSource$1@2d27b1d rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@a8f7192[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 1]_

Comment: If it is being rejected then you are limiting the size of your queue @HudiIlfeld.   This should not happen if you are calling `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();`.

Comment: Like you can see in my code I am indeed using Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(); yet I am getting this error.

Comment: AHA.  I bet you shutdown your thread-pool.  You should keep it running forever until the application is being shutdown @HudiIlfeld.

Comment: so where do I put the `service.shutdown();` exactly? in other words when. does the app shutdown? in the `onBackpressed()` method? and plus wouldn't it be better to shutdown an additional thread when it's task is finalized rather. then keeping it running during the hole lifecycle of the app? @Gray.